# Distinct equivalence classes of the relation $R$ defined on $\mathbb Z$ defined by $mRn$ if $5 \mid m^3 - n^3$

Tags: relations, congruences

I am wondering how to describe the distinct classes of $[2]$ and $[3]$.

For $[2]$ I got $[2] = \{5k + 3: k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

For $[3]$ I got $[3] = \{5k + 2: k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

But apparently these are switched around. How come? This is from my exam that I recently wrote and I really thought I had it. Any help?

PS: Forgive me for the poor formatting. I am still trying to learn how to do it as I am relatively new to the site.

Comment: If you can prove that it is an equivalence relation in the first place, you should know that $x\in[x]$ since equivalence relations are reflexive.  If you say you got $[2]=\{5k+3~:~k\in\Bbb Z\}$ and you realize that $2\not\in\{5k+3~:~k\in\Bbb Z\}$ then you should have been immediately suspicious that a mistake had occurred.

Answer (score 1):

$$0^3 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$$
$$1^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$$
$$2^3 \equiv 3 \pmod{5}$$
$$3^3 \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$$
$$4^3 \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$$

\begin{align}[2]&=\{n:2^3\equiv n^3 \pmod{5}\}\\&=\{n:3 \equiv n^3 \pmod{5}\}\\
&=\{n: n \equiv 2 \pmod{5}\} \end{align}